# Can you use regular expressions to find all possibilities of 6 characters from a 10 character string in another string?

Tags: regex

Can you use regular expressions to find all possibilities of 6 characters from a 10 character string in another string?

Let's say you have a string '0123456789'.  You have another string '123456'.  Is there a way to use regular expressions to say there is a match between '0123456789' and '123456'?  This regular expression would also need to match '012345', '234567', '345678', '456789' and '0012345600'.

Comment: No, pure regex by itself cannot do this.  Are you using a programming language?

Comment: You can use the regexp `012345|123456|234567|345678|456789`. If you need to generate this dynamically from the 10-character string, you'll need a programming language for that.

Comment: I have programming languages available.  I was thinking sometimes regex can do with one line what you need 10 lines in a programming language.